# MySQL ERROR 1064 - MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

As I have searched, it is a common error and for each case the solution is different. I'm new in database designing. But what is strange to me is that this error is given to me because of running an **automatic** SQL command generated by MySQL Workbench!

```
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ,
  CONSTRAINT `officialLanguage`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`la' at line 9
SQL Statement:

CREATE  TABLE `mydb`.`countries` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  `shortName` VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
  `nativeName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `url` VARCHAR(80) NULL ,
  `countryCode` VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `officialLanguage` () ,
  CONSTRAINT `officialLanguage`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`languages` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

each part I change or remove does not solve the issue.

It is the second table.

for the first table that had no foreign key, I had no problem:

```
CREATE  TABLE `mydb`.`languages` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(20) NULL ,
  `shortName` VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
  `nativeName` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );
```

---

Solved thanks to Ed Gibbs

I was thinking I was the blamable!

```
CREATE  TABLE `mydb`.`countries` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL ,
  `shortName` VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
  `nativeName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `url` VARCHAR(80) NULL ,
  `countryCode` VARCHAR(10) NULL ,
  `officialLanguage` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `officialLanguage` (`officialLanguage`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `officialLanguage`
    FOREIGN KEY (`officialLanguage`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`languages` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Comment: The index creation doesn't have the column names. Same with the foreign keys (`REFERENCES ...`). I think I had the same problem way back, which is why I stopped using Workbench for my `CREATE` scripts. That and the sea of backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `officialLanguage` there are empty parenthesis. Column name is missing.

Same after `mydb`.`languages`.